# Batch image resizing and rotating on OS X?

Tags: macos, batch, image-editing

I'd like to resize a bunch of images of variable size to be 720 by 480. Furthermore, I'd like to have the final image be rotated so that it is right side up. Any tools to help with the resizing at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it right from inside iPhoto according to [Ask Lifehacker: batch resize photos, part II](https://lifehacker.com/ask-lifehacker-batch-resize-photos-part-ii-37951)

Basically you highlight what you want to resize and export them and set the custom size in the export settings.

As for the rotation, you can do that in iPhoto too, but not automatically I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Use Automator. There are actions for Scale Images, Crop Images, and Rotate Images. Detailed instructions here:

[Batch Resize Images, With Automator (Archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304171612/http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2010/01/batch-resize-images-with-automator.html)